# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

An integral related to the zeta function at the point $2$ is given by

$$\zeta(2) = \int\nolimits_0^\infty \dfrac{t}{e^t - 1}\mathrm dt$$

How to calculate this integral?

Comment: Well... you already did (compute this integral), didn't you? Since you know its value. Or do you want a **proof** that it is indeed zeta(2)?

Comment: Choose a random integer and check if it is divisible by a square.

Comment: @Dan: ?? $ $ $ $

Comment: Didier, throw a needle!

Comment: @Didier: it's a rather long-winded gag... :)

Comment: @J.M. I had guessed so and this is precisely my point.

Comment: Is the fact that the function being integrated is the generating function of the Bernoulli numbers of interest here?

Comment: @Michael Hardy:  Yes it is of interest.  We can see this directly with the "notion" of a negative Bernoulli number. (Non rigorous, it might be possible to make it rigorous though)  The generating series fact can be reworded as $$B_n =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{x}{e^x-1}.$$  In some "sense" the integral of $\frac{t}{e^t-1}$ should be like $B_{-1}$ since we would want to take $n=-1$.  Recall as well that $-n\zeta(1-n)=B_n$ for positive $n$.  If we "define" the negative Bernoulli numbers by that formula as well, then $B_{-1}=\zeta(2)$.  Voilà.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the $n$th cumulant of the uniform distribution on the interval $[-1,0]$ is $B_n/n$.  Does it make sense to ask why the $n$th cumulant of that distribution should be $-\zeta(1-n)$?

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=n!\cdot\zeta(n+1)$$

Answer (score 5):

The integrand can be expressed as a geometric series with first term $te^{-t}$ and common ratio $e^{-t}$. Integrate term-by-term (after justifying it, of course) and see if you don't recognize the result as $\zeta(2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat equivalent to Gerry's answer: let $t=-\log(1-u)$, giving the integral

$$-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)}{u}\mathrm du$$

Expand the logarithm as a series, swap summation and integration, and then you should be able to see something familiar...

Comment: Or notice that this integral is the dilogarithm evaluated at $1$.  Wait, I guess you prove that $\text{Li}_2 (1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by expanding the integral anyway so nevermind....

Comment: @Eric: I didn't want to bring it up. You're right, of course. ;)